# Why does the await keyword not work within an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, arrow-functions

Why does

```
names.forEach((name) => {
    images.push(await loadImage(name));
})
```

not work, but

```
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    images.push(await loadImage(names[i]));
}
```

does?

note: loadImage just returns a Promise, giving a loaded Image() 
 
names is a string-list

Comment: the anonymous function isn't an async function.

Comment: `await` needs to be in a `async` function.

Comment: you are missing `async` declaration - `async name => { ... }` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first parameter within `forEach` is it's own function. To use `await` within a function the function MUST be marked as `async`. It works in the loop because there is no new function, and presumably the function you are running the loop in is marked as `async`. So, to make the `forEach` work, you need to do:

```
names.forEach(async (name) => {
    images.push(await loadImage(name));
})
```

However, that's not the best thing. Really you want to gather the promises and then wait for them all to finish:

```
const promises = names.map(name => loadImage(name));
const images = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: *"However, that's not the best thing, because you will be running them all synchronously. Really you want to gather the promises and then wait for them all to finish"* i mean, technically, .map is running them synchronously too, it just makes passing the result to .all easier.

Comment: @KevinB that's not true. My code fires them all off synchronously, and then waits for them all to finish in parallel. The `forEach` code above will wait for each one to finish before running the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: No, forEach will not wait. a for loop would. Both cases in your answer will run all the requests in parallel.

Comment: @KevinB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop